# Is there any solution for avoiding data truncating in pdf export of rpt design file in eclipse?

Tags: birt

There are about 15 columns in my report file in birt eclipse. I have been facing issue of data truncating/ column cutting while exporting to pdf. Is there any way we can avoid truncation and show full content in pdf or can suggest any alternative for this problem

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following options (assuming you are using the POJO or OSGI runtime) and task is a `RunAndRenderTask` or a `RenderTask`:

```
                PDFRenderOption pdfOptions = new PDFRenderOption(options);
                pdfOptions.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PAGE_OVERFLOW, IPDFRenderOption.OUTPUT_TO_MULTIPLE_PAGES);

                pdfOptions.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PDF_TEXT_WRAPPING, true);
                pdfOptions.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PDF_WORDBREAK, true);
                task.setRenderOption(options);
```

before calling task.render() or task.run() depending on task's class.

In older releases of BIRT, `PDF_WORBREAK` was called `PDF_HYPHENATION` IIRC.

This option caused words that don't fit into a single line to break, eg.

supercalif
ragilistic

Note that is is not true hyphenation, which would mean to break between syllables. That's why the option was renamed.

Comment: My birt folder consists of javascript files and jsp files.I assume it is using some window.print() methods (chrome plugin/mozilla plugin).I would like to know whether the above mentioned statements can be used in js also.

Comment: It seems that these options cannot be set without modifying the Java code of the Viewer *.war file.